# Adding functions to std::string in c++

Tags: c++, string, class, inheritance, std

I just miss some functions in the c++ standard library string class, so I just wanted to add these by myself. I wrote this:

```
#include <string>


class String : public std::string
{
public:
    // some new fancy functions
};
```

and later noticed by reading some forums, that it is a bad idea to inherit from std::string and any other container from the standard library.

I just want the normal string, but with additional functions written by myself, how can I achieve this in the right way? Or is there no way to do it right and I have to right my own string class?

Comment: This is the most right way of doing it, and it is usually a bad idea. If you want new functionalities, you are better off writing functions that work with `std::string` instead. Bonus points if they are generic and work with other containers too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### tl;dr: Use freestanding functions.

First of all - `std::string` is kind of a mess, and has too many methods as-is. It's bad design to lump functionality into a class which doesn't need to be in that class, and can easily be implemented using simpler, more basic class methods - as a freestanding function.

Moreover - `std::string` is at the same time unwieldy to manipulate (it's not a string buffer or an `std::stringstream`), and not impossible to manipulate, i.e. not immutable.

But coming back to my earlier point: The "right way" - if there is any - to do what you wanted is with freestanding functions. For example, suppose you want to randomly permute the contents of an `std::string`. Well, either:

```
std::string& jumble(std::string& str)
```

or

```
std::string jumble(std::string str)
```

or maybe, if you want to feel cool and micro-optimized,

```
std::string jumble(const std::string& str)
std::string jumble(std::string&& str)
```

depending if you want to use strings more as immutable or as mutable entities.

Also remember, that we don't really have a single `std::string` class - we have a template based on the character type (and an allocator etc.), so if you want to be generic, you have to accept this class:

```
template<
    class CharT,
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> class basic_string;
```

---

PS - If we had uniform call syntax, like [Bjarne proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4174.pdf) - which we really should IMHO - your freestanding functions could simply be invoked as though they were members:

```
auto jumbled = my_string.jumble();
```

Comment: Oh, please not uniform call syntax. One of the strengths of C/C++ is, that they call the different things by their proper names, and don't try to hide complexity behind automagic facades. Well, C much more so than C++, actually. Uniform call syntax would just be another step to turn the already hopelessly overfeatured C++ into something like javascript, which may look slick at the first glance, but actually makes it pretty hard to deduce what a statement actually does. Of course, C++ has always moved into that direction, `auto` being the worst offender, but every further step is harmful imho.

Comment: "Uniform call syntax" would actually make things more explicit and C-like. It would reflect the inherent reality of a (non-static) method being just a function which takes a "this" pointer, can access private members, and has some syntactic sugar to avoid saying "this->" all the time. It would be very clear that if you write `x.bar(y)` you really mean `bar(&x, y)` - just as `a->z` is the same as saying `(*a).z`.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica, also with the help of IntelliSense of modern editors/IDEs whenever you put your cursor on `auto`, it will say you what type exactly it is, but in javascript you can't realize which type has a variable! as you know `auto` is a compile-time feature so it's easy to detect what it is for any editor and IDEs. and it makes life to get easier for us.

Comment: @SdSaati Which means that a) I must use some IDE to even *read* the code, and b) I must use my mouse. Both things that I'd rather avoid or might not even have. Like when viewing source code online, or when being logged into some machine via `ssh`. An explicitly written type a) works independent of tooling, b) reflects programmer intention rather than compiler understanding, and c) produces an error when the two don't match up. I realize that this is hard to understand for someone who's not been socialized with explicit types, but for old hands like me, types carry a lot of meaning.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica even vim can detect and show that, it also works inside ssh, tmux and every other environment, being explicit is Ok, but I just wanted to mention that javascript var is not the same as auto in C++

Comment: @SdSaati Even in `vim`, I would need to place a cursor. My eyes are faster than my cursor, be it text or mouse. And yes, I know that there is a *big* difference between deduced static typing (C++) and dynamic typing (JavaScript). Nevertheless I've come to appreciate seeing types written explicitly at the point of the variable declaration, even though I know that it's more trouble to type. Speaking of typing, shouldn't your IDE also help you with filling out your explicit types? Like, whenever you write `auto`, it instantly fills in the deduced type? If not, why?

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica true, explicit is better no doubt, I use auto for those places that the type is obvious for everyone but it's so long to write.